# When i use partitionBy in window,why i get a different result with spark/scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use `Window.sum` function to get the sum of a value in an RDD, but when I convert the DataFrame to an RDD, I found that the result's has only one partition. When does the repartitioning occur?

```
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8), 4)
    val df = rdd.toDF("values").
        withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.orderBy("values")))
    df.show()
    println(s"numPartitions ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
    // 1
    //df is:
//    +------+----+
//    |values|csum|
//    +------+----+
//    |     1|   1|
//    |     2|   3|
//    |     3|   6|
//    |     4|  10|
//    |     5|  15|
//    |     6|  21|
//    |     7|  28|
//    |     8|  36|
//    +------+----+
```

I add partitionBy in Window ,but the result is error,what should i do?this is my change code:

```
     val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(m_sparkCtx)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val df = rdd.toDF("values").withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.partitionBy("values").orderBy("values")))
        df.show()
        println(s"numPartitions ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
       //1
//df is:
//    +------+----+
//    |values|csum|
//    +------+----+
//    |     1|   1|
//    |     6|   6|
//    |     3|   3|
//    |     5|   5|
//    |     4|   4|
//    |     8|   8|
//    |     7|   7|
//    |     2|   2|
//    +------+----+
```

Comment: I just answered this in your other question. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Window` function has `partitionBy` api for grouping the `dataframe` and `orderBy` to order the grouped rows in ascending or descending order.

In your first case you hadn't defined `partitionBy`, thus all the values were grouped in one `dataframe` for ordering purpose and thus shuffling the data into one partition.

But in your second case you had `partitionBy` defined on `values` itself. So since each value are distinct, each row is grouped into individual groups.

The partition in second case is 200 as that is the default partitioning defined in `spark` when you haven't defined partitions and shuffle occurs

To get the same result from your second case as you get with the first case, you need to group your `dataframe` as in your first case i.e. into one group. For that you will need to create another `column` with constant value and use that value for `partitionBy`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a column  as
`withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.orderBy("values")))`

The  `Window.orderBy("values")` is ordering the values of column "values" in single partition since you haven't defined `partitionBy()` method to define the partition.

This is changing the number of `partition` from initial 4 to 1.

The partition is 200 in your second case since the `partitionBy()`method uses 200 as default partition. if you need the number of partition as 4 you can use methods like `repartition(4)` or `coalesce(4)`

Hope you got the point!